# SuiteCRM - fix file permissions

Tags: bash, syntax, suitecrm

I am trying to update the file permissions for SuiteCRM.

I need to run the following code in GNU bash, but I cannot figure out the correct syntax to list the file permissions.

I am the root user

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .

sudo chmod -R 755 .

sudo chmod -R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload

sudo chmod 775 config_override.php 2>/dev/null
```

Version is GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) correct syntax for file permissions

Comment: you want to **change** or just **list** the file permission?

Comment: If you want to just list try just `ls -al` or `ll`

Comment: Hi Kent I am trying to change the file permissions .

Comment: *"I cannot figure out the correct syntax to list the file permissions."* . Please clarify the text of your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

For SuiteCRM this is what I do for resetting permissions (you have to be root before executing)

Please adjust to your web server user (this one is for ubuntu )

```
find . -type d ! -path ./vendor -exec chmod 0755 {} \; &&  find . -type f ! -path ./vendor -exec chmod 0644 {} \; 
chmod -R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload  config_override.php  config.php
chown -R www-data:www-data .
```

For redhat the apache webserver usually runs as `apache` user so you should run:

```
find . -type d ! -path ./vendor -exec chmod 0755 {} \; &&  find . -type f ! -path ./vendor -exec chmod 0644 {} \; 
chmod -R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload  config_override.php  config.php
chown -R apache:apache .
```

The first line makes sure all files are `644` and all folders are `755` just to make sure you don't have weird permissions.

Last but not least, ONLY in the case that someone has SuPHP you will need to run `chown apache.nobody ./` for redhat and `chown www-data.nobody ./` as apache usually runs as nobody and needs access to the root folder + SuPHP might complain of group write permissions on some folders so adjust :)

EDIT: Excluded the vendor folder which has its own file permissions needs (bin folder has executable files)

Answer (score 0):

This would be fine I guess for changing permission for all the files recursively

```
sudo chmod -r 755 *
```