# Suite CRM Undefined Error in labels and other areas

Tags: javascript, php, suitecrm

I changed all the necessary file/folder permissions (cache, custom, modules, themes, data, upload,config_override.php). Then did a "Quick Repair and Rebuild", still it's not working (screenshot attached). Please help.

[image: Screenshot Undefined Error]

Comment: What exactly are you asking? With what code problem can we help? Your question is unclear.

Comment: No coding problem. See the table headers <th>and other headers are undefined.  .htaccess has been rebuild and file permissions are set to 777

Answer (score 0):

Undefined labels are usually either 2 things

1. File permissions. If any of the required permissions are not correctly set the repair and rebuild will fail.
2. htaccess. This may cause a 404 when trying to

For #1 check this other answer [SuiteCRM - fix file permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439416/suitecrm-fix-file-permissions/52444737#52444737)

For #2 check the console for 404 JS files.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you tell me the necessary file/folders I need to set 777 permissions for this issue? There is no js file missing error in the console.

Comment: 777 is never recommended, check the linked resource in my #1 response to execute the permissions. 775 file mode is usually set to:  `cache custom modules themes data upload  config_override.php  config.php`